# iOS App Exception - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, iphone, exception

I am getting the following exception, which is terminating the app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7abe4f90'

Following is the code:

```
- (NSMutableData*)dataForConnection:(URLConnection*)connection {       
NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:connection.tagKey]; // Exception Here
return data;
}
```

Could anyone please suggest how to fix it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is due to not allocating receivedData properly, since you have declared it as instance variable, so you should make it using the property declaration like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *receivedData;
```

This will ensure that receivedData does not get released and reference this using self.receivedData in your code.
Maybe this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

`[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]`

`NSArray` have not method called `objectForKey:`

Your object `receivedData` is `NSArray` class , change to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you @Nick . It is defined as

NSMutableDictionary* receivedData;

Should I change it to NSDictionary?

Comment: No ！U defined receivedData as  NSMutableDictionary class. But  receivedData become "NSMutableArray" class at u exception code.
Show "receivedData " define code !

Sorry ! My English is not very good!

Comment: so what I should change? I am sorry as I am new to Objective C

Comment: Show more code about object  "receivedData "  for me .

Comment: Here is the receivedData used in main finction

-(void)call
{
    
    urlConnection = [[URLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES
                                                       tag: APITag];
    
    receivedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    
    if (urlConnection) {
        responseData=[NSMutableData data];
        [receivedData setObject:responseData forKey:urlConnection.tagKey];
    }
    
    [urlConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [urlConnection start];

}

Comment: And in the other function like below:

`-(void)callPOST
{    
    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    receivedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    
    if (urlConnection) {
        responseData=[NSMutableData data];
        [receivedData setObject:responseData forKey:urlConnection.tagKey];
    }
    
    [urlConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [urlConnection start];
    
}`

Comment: Can you show the initial declaration of receivedData

Comment: These code have no problem for " receviedData".
Maybe u can send your project or .m file witch have problem  to me with Email .
my Email address is yingwei_work@163.com

Comment: Yes sure @user1000 , Following is the initial declaration:

`NSMutableDictionary* receivedData;`

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code...you can try NSLog(receivedData) to see what it contains before this line : NSMutableData *data = [receivedData objectForKey:connection.tagKey];

Comment: Thank you @Nick I have emailed you file.

Comment: @user1000 I did that and it contains:

<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7aba4110>

Comment: Yes sure @user1000 Please see.

`2017-07-26 12:44:40.730 SwipeHQC[33810:1835341] <__NSMallocBlock__: 0x7aba4110>
2017-07-26 12:44:40.730 SwipeHQC[33810:1835341] -[__NSMallocBlock__ objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aba4110
2017-07-26 12:44:40.735 SwipeHQC[33810:1835341] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7aba4110'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: Please try this: @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *receivedData;

Comment: then use self.receivedData rather than receivedData in your code

Comment: remove the declaration of receivedData that you did before

Comment: Please check and tell me

Comment: @user1000 I added `@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *receivedData; ` before the exception line and cjhnage that to self.receivedData but editor shows error, Unexpected '@' in program.

Comment: @Yas write this line where you are declaring receivedData not in this function

Comment: I have receviced your Email . But i cant run it.  And i can't find any wrong in code . 
 I guess he are right . 
He defined receivedData like this
@interface SwipeHQAPICall ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData * responseData;
    NSMutableDictionary * receivedData;
    NSString * APITag;
    NSString * url;
    URLConnection * urlConnection;
    NSString * baseUrl;
    NSString * postData;
}
Maybe  receivedData is released when call it.  so ,try this guy's suggestion！

Comment: @user1000 Okay, I wrote this in the top where it was declared before, but there it shows, `Expected ';' at the end of declaration list`

I wrote
`@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *receivedData;`

Please suggest..

Comment: @interface SwipeHQAPICall ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate> { NSMutableData * responseData; NSString * APITag; NSString * url; URLConnection * urlConnection; NSString * baseUrl; NSString * postData; }
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *receivedData;

Comment: Thank you @user1000 The issue is resolved.

Got next but not relevant to this :)

Comment: Thank you @Nick too for your help.

Comment: Please see my answer does it solve your problem? If yes then please accept it  otherwise tell how you solved the problem or you can tell which comment was useful for you by upvoting it so others can take help